# Error al llamar una función php desde el evento onclick

Tags: php, html

Me pasa lo siguiente:

Llamo a una función `php` desde el evento `onclick`, mi problema es que la función php se ejecuta siempre que se carga la página, es decir, ignora el `onclick`.

```
<a href="archivo.pdf" onclick="funcion()"/a>
```

- Probe llamando a la función que está en una página php.
- Probe llamando a la página php.
- Probe llamando a una función javascript y en esta función está el
  llamado a la función php.

En todos los casos me pasa lo mismo, la función php se ejecuta siempre que se carga la página ignora el onclick.

```
$visitas1 = array();
$visitas1 = contVisitas1();

function contVisitas1(){ 

    $archivo = "contador1.txt"; 
    $info = array(); 

    if (file_exists($archivo)){ 
        $fp = fopen($archivo,"r"); 
        $contador = fgets($fp, 26); 
        $info = explode(" ",$contador); 
        fclose($fp); 

        $mes_actual = date("m"); 
        $mes_ultimo = $info[0]; 
        $visitas_mes = $info[1]; 
        $visitas_totales = $info[2]; 
    }else{ 
        $mes_actual = date("m"); 
        $mes_ultimo = "0"; 
        $visitas_mes = 0; 
        $visitas_totales = 0; 
    } 

    if ($mes_actual==$mes_ultimo){ 
        $visitas_mes++; 
    }else{ 
        $visitas_mes=1; 
    } 
    $visitas_totales++; 

    $info[0] = $mes_actual; 
    $info[1] = $visitas_mes; 
    $info[2] = $visitas_totales; 

    $info_nueva = implode(" ",$info); 
    $fp = fopen($archivo,"w+"); 
    fwrite($fp, $info_nueva, 26); 
    fclose($fp); 

    return $info;

}
```

Comment: Es decir que quieres hacer AJAX desde un evento `onclick`? Pero estoy de acuerdo con @Darkhogg - necesitamos ver un ejemplo.

Comment: <a href="Archivo.pdf" onclick="funcion.php" /a>

Comment: @Natalia ¿Qué contiene `funcion.php`? Añade este tipo de detalles a la pregunta, no como un simple comentario.

Comment: Es un código para contabilizar la cantidad de veces que se abre un archivo .pdf

Comment: @Natalia Insisto: No utilices los comentarios para esto, **añade ese código a la pregunta**.

Comment: @Natalia, por favor edita tu pregunta, los comentarios no es lugar para poner el código

Comment: puede ver compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, puede acceder a editar presionado sobre el, le recomiendo que entre para que pueda ver como se formatea el codigo para que se muestre como esta ahora , basicamente es poner 4 spc, pero lo puede hacer seleccionando el codigo en el modo edicion y pulsando sobre { } que esta en la parte superior donde escribe el codigo, para futuras preguntas/respuesta Saludos

Comment: Hola Natalia, por favor te recomiendo que leas http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para familiarizarte con el funcionamiento del sitio

Answer (score 5):

Si quieres ejecutar código en el servidor, tienes que enviar una petición de una u otra manera. Para hacerlo sin navegar a otra página (o actualizar la misma), se usa AJAX. Por lo tanto, debemos diferenciar entre PHP que se ejecuta en el servidor, y JavaScript que se ejecuta en el lado cliente (ordenador, móvil, tablet...).

Es un tema muy amplio, asi que no voy a intentar explicarlo en su totalidad, pero mostraré un pequeño ejemplo. Para no complicarme la vida, uso [`jQuery.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) (enlace en inglés), pero sí que se puede hacerlo sin ninguna biblioteca si quieres.

**HTML**

```
<script>
function ajax() {
    jQuery.get("ajax.php").then(function (respuesta) {
        document.getElementById("resultado").value = respuesta;
    });
}
</script>
<button onclick="ajax()">pulsa</button>
<textarea id="resultado"></textarea>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php    
echo '¡Hola, mundo!';
```

Cuando pulsas el botón, se le enviará una petición "GET" al servidor de forma asíncrona. Cuando termine, la respuesta del servidor se pone en el `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 2):

Estás mezclando dos lenguajes que se ejecutan en distintas partes
el php se ejecuta en el servidor cuando se genera el documento
el javascript se ejecuta en el browser

el evento onClick va a llamar una funcion de javascript que debes programar en ese lenguaje

si lo que quieres es que en ese momento pase algo en el servidor puedes usar ajax para llamar a **otro** script pho en el servidor que realice la acción que desees

Answer (score 1):

'onclick', es un evento de JavaScript que se ejecuta en el navegador, por eso si no tienes ningún método que maneje ese evento siempre te va a cargar lo que tengas en el href. Yo te recomendaría que en el href hicieras una referencia al archivo php que tiene el método y posteriormente descargues el archivo.

```html
contVisitas1();

function contVisitas1(){ 

    $archivo = "contador1.txt"; 
    $info = array(); 

    if (file_exists($archivo)){ 
        $fp = fopen($archivo,"r"); 
        $contador = fgets($fp, 26); 
        $info = explode(" ",$contador); 
        fclose($fp); 

        $mes_actual = date("m"); 
        $mes_ultimo = $info[0]; 
        $visitas_mes = $info[1]; 
        $visitas_totales = $info[2]; 
    }else{ 
        $mes_actual = date("m"); 
        $mes_ultimo = "0"; 
        $visitas_mes = 0; 
        $visitas_totales = 0; 
    } 

    if ($mes_actual==$mes_ultimo){ 
        $visitas_mes++; 
    }else{ 
        $visitas_mes=1; 
    } 
    $visitas_totales++; 

    $info[0] = $mes_actual; 
    $info[1] = $visitas_mes; 
    $info[2] = $visitas_totales; 

    $info_nueva = implode(" ",$info); 
    $fp = fopen($archivo,"w+"); 
    fwrite($fp, $info_nueva, 26); 
    fclose($fp); 

    return $info;

}

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$file = "archivo.pdf";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); 
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); 
} 
fclose($fp);
```

```html
<a href="funcion.php">Descargar</a>
```